# eDiscovery REST or Java API support

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, ediscovery

Is there any REST / JAVA Api to create cases in eDiscivery center in Sharepoint 2013/Sharepoint Online?

If so please provide the link/samples.

Comment: Check these examples [JShare Online Tutorial](http://www.independentsoft.de/jshare)

Answer (score 1):

There is no REST endpoints for eDiscovery.

Please refer [SharePoint developer reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/jj860569.aspx)